# error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge: .DS_Store

Tags: git, macos, git-push, git-pull

I have a git repository on a mac, when I use `git status` in terminal it says

```
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

when I try to pull changes from repository `git pull repositoryName master`

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
.DS_Store
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
```

so I tried to remove it with `git rm .DS_Store` but it says

```
fatal: pathspec '.DS_Store' did not match any files
```

I then tried to remove the cached file and add it again with `git rm --cached . -r` and `git add .` with a .gitignore directive that would ignore .DS_Store but the problem still persists.

I tried lots of commands that I saw on different posts without success. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> .DS_Store

is a Mac related file that is created every time you touch some directory (if I'm not mistaken, it is used for indexing).

So, first you don't have it. Then you try to bring some files/folders into your directory (and thus it gets created - breaking your pull command).

In your repo directory create a file called **.gitignore** and inside it have a single line (so far) **.DS_Store**. This should fix your problem.

Comment: even after adding it to gitignore, still I'm getting the same error

Comment: make sure you delete the .DS_Store file also from the repository. The git error message comes from the fact that the conflicting file is in your directory (created by Finder while navigating/changing view settings/sorting) and git wants to overwrite it with the one in the repository.

Answer (score 16):

```
rm .DS_Store
```

I ran the above command on the repo folder. and finally could pull from git.
I suggest you add `.DS_Store` in your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Problem is if you add a `.gitignore` you see a new issue: `error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
 .gitignore`

Comment: So commit your change on `.gitignore` and push to the git.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by deleting `.DS_Store` from the git origin repository.

Answer (score 1):

When you `mkdir` your folder, you can enter this command `git init` and then pull. That will solve your problem.