# How do I deal with git error resulting from pulling commit on MacOs involving files whose filename has case differences

Tags: git, macos

I get the following error from git when trying to pull (or checkout or cherry-pick) a commit involving files whose filename has changed only in terms of upper vs. lower case:

```
The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge
```

after which it lists all the files with only case differences. A `git status` shows nothing in my working directory.

I was able to perform the `pull` successfully after first deleting the local copy of the files in question, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to work around, or better yet, *avoid* the problem in the first place. Other users running on MacOS with the same repository on their local machines had no such symptoms/problem.

Comment: If you can, rename (or possibly delete when applicable) all the files and folders that differ only by casing. Then commit the change and push it out to the repo so nobody else has this issue again. If you can't do that, then perhaps try to work in an OS and filesystem combo that is setup to handle case sensitive filenames. (AFAIK Mac and Windows by default are not.)

Comment: Looking at the commit you are on, and the one you are trying to move to with `checkout`, do both files (with different casing) exist in one or both commits, or, was the file renamed with different casing between those two commits? (Or instead of renamed, it could be deleted and then re-added with the new casing.)

Comment: Ultimately I'm trying to figure out the reason for this: "Other uses running on MacOS with the same repository on their local machines had no such symptoms/problem." The thing that is different could be that only you are switching between commits where the casing differs (which maybe can be answered by my previous question.) Or, I think MacOS allows you to turn on a case sensitive file system, and maybe the other users have that on? (I doubt this though because I don't think it's just a switch you can flip. AFAIK you have to reformat a drive...)

Comment: The files exist in both commits and were renamed. Setting the global config property recommended in the answer below seems to have resolved the problem for me. I'm going to check that property on others' systems.

Comment: Can you run this command : `git config --list --show-origin | grep -i ignorecase` and post result ? It's a little strange that `git config --global` helped because core.ignoreCase is usually set at repo level.

Comment: On macOS, when you create or format a volume with the APFS or HFS+ format, you can choose to make it case sensitive or not.

Comment: after you rename a file, also rename it using `git mv oldname newname`

Answer (score 2):

#### If case-sensitivity is required

[The `git` utility assumes your filesystem is case-sensitive](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/git-is-casesensitive-and-your-filesystem-may-not-be-weird-folder-merging-on-windows) because most, if not all, Linux and FreeBSD filesystems are so.
But on macOS, by default the file system is case-insensitive. This mismatch can result in the problems you are seeing.

If case-sensitivity ***is not*** required by the project/code, you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74825318/8910547).

If case-sensitivity ***is*** required, and you are operating on macOS with a case-insensitive file system, you can make a new virtual case-sensitive volume sharing the same APFS partition as your other volumes.

You would use the new case-sensitive volume exclusively for your git repo work. If you compile an application on this volume, you can test it with configuration and data files on your other case-insensitive volumes if required.

Open Disk Utility and click the `+` button for a new Volume:

[image: disk utility]

Name the new Volume:

[image: new volume]

Store your files in this directory:

```
% ls -ld /Volumes/GitRepo
drwxr-xr-x  5 risner  staff  160 Dec 15 21:25 /Volumes/GitRepo
```

Comment: be advised that having a case sensitive filesystem changes the rules for your programs too. e.g: if your program is expected to run on MacOS, and your expect `open(config.ini)` to also work with `Config.ini`, on that file system they wouldn't anymore.

Comment: I wasn't clear, this new Volume is virtual. It's only purpose is to house the case-sensitive git files. All the other macOS files would be in case-insensitive volumes.

Comment: I think I understood that part, I meant: if the user tests his program from within his repo directory (this is how most projects I know work), he wouldn't test the same behavior as his production behavior -- if his production runs on a case insensitive filesystem.

Comment: I see, thanks. That is a good point. I guess I assumed one wouldn't do that, as I don't tend to do so. I'll consider how to caution. I should have caught this edge case.

Comment: This answer only makes sense if the codebase *should* be case-sensitive. Otherwise it is an overly inconvenient solution, impacting the organization of your repos on your machine. I think the [micromoses answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74825318/8910547) is the right general solution.

Comment: @Inigo their solution actively fails on Linux kernel source as it has multiple files with only case differences.

Comment: As I point out in my first sentence.

Comment: I guess I run into code based that do this so often for the other solution.

Answer (score 1):

> "Other uses running on MacOS with the same repository on their local machines had no such symptoms/problem."

On case insensitive file systems: the names of the files on a user's disk keep a trace of the sequence of actions that happened on that user machine. Once a file is created on disk (either because a `git swicth` or `git pull` created on disk a new file with the casing listed in git, or because the user named the file himself) it will retain that casing.

To illustrate this : on Windows and MacOS, `mv Readme.md README.md` is a no-op -- even if the file is actually named `rEaDmE.md`, it will keep its initial name.

In a similar way: if you switch between branches where a specific file is named either `Readme.md` or `README.md`, the name of the file on your disk will actually not change -- it will keep the name it initially had.

So you may end up with a repo on your disk where files have not the same names as on your colleague's disk, just because you happened to `git pull` the `feature-xyz` branch before switching to `master`.

---

To spot discrepancies between your files on disk and the names in git, you can compare `git ls-files` with `git ls-files | xargs ls` :

```
diff <(git ls-files) <(git ls-files | xargs ls)
```

(*note:* I don't have a MacOS filesystem at hand, I hope `ls readme.md` will output `README.md` if the file on disk is actually in uppercase, and that `git ls-files | xargs ls` will show *the actual case of your names on your filesystem* rather than just repeating the output of `git ls-files`)

A common workaround to rename files on Windows/MacOS is to use a temporary name :

```
mv Readme.md tmp-name && mv tmp-name README.md
```

Same thing goes for `git mv` : `git mv Readme.md README.md` will succesfully change the name *stored in git* but not *the name on disk*.

You can :

```
git mv Readme.md tmp-name && git mv tmp-name README.md
```

If your intention is to have your files on disk match the names in git, you may use the output of the first command to issue renaming commands.

Comment: what about `git mv src dest`

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly: I included a remark about `git mv`

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

Having trouble with case-sensitive file/directory renames in a git repo on a case-insensitive FS/OS; Follow these 3 steps:

1. Make sure `git config --global core.ignorecase` returns nothing, or at the very least `true`. If `false` - reset to null, so git can autodetect this configuration according to the filesystem a repo is cloned onto.
2. In your repo, if it resides on a case-insensitive filesystem (or OS), make sure `git config core.ignorecase` is set to `true`. If none or false - set to true.
3. Update git to the latest version.

#### The problem

Git was built on, and therefore most compatible with, case-sensitive filesystems. As git became more popular its application on case-insensitive filesystems increased, and so did the amount of issues found and bugs opened for case handling incompatibilities. Don't get me wrong - these issues *were* (and if still open - *are* being) addressed, but still a rocky road.
I cannot recommend formatting an entire filesystem to be case-sensitive as a resolution, as it may break other applications which expect filenames to be case-agnostic. True story.

### The progress

This is just my personal opinion, but I feel like things have drastically shifted for git enthusiasts in the past 15 years, from requiring a case-sensitive formatted FS, to better (and almost seamless) handling of case-insensitivities by git itself.

### The "why did I tell this so long story?" part

An ad-hoc method can be employed to resolve a specific file-rename causing problems, but that is a workaround - not a solution. Git should be able to handle insensitive filesystems "out-of-the-box":

> **core.ignoreCase**
> Internal variable which enables various workarounds to enable Git to work better on filesystems that are not case sensitive, like APFS, HFS+, FAT, NTFS, etc. For example, if a directory listing finds "makefile" when Git expects "Makefile", Git will assume it is really the same file, and continue to remember it as "Makefile".
>
> The default is false, except git-clone(1) or git-init(1) will probe and set core.ignoreCase true if appropriate when the repository is created.
>
> Git relies on the proper configuration of this variable for your operating and file system. Modifying this value may result in unexpected behavior.

Git should be able to handle file/directory letter-case-renames automatically when cloning or initializing a repository on an insensitive environment. There will be problems, of course, if the repository contains two paths that should coexist, and differ only in letter-case (e.g. `mypath/myfile.txt` and `mypath/MyFile.txt`) - this is not possible on an insensitive filesystem. Another reason for trouble is if the repository was first cloned/initialized on a case-sensitive FS, but later physically moved (`mv`/`cp`) to an insensitive one; in such case setting the repository's `core.ignorecase` config to true should make things better.

Still, while git "should" be able to handle such cases, it is important to keep git up-to-date. As issues are discovered, newer versions have them resolved, making for a much smoother experience. I'm posting some examples from the release notes; These are **NOT** to be regarded as a "shame list" in any way, but rather to show the engagement of the maintainers and the goals they achieved towards seamless support for case-insensitive FS/OS. And to convince the ones who managed to read so far of the importance of software updates:

- **Fixed in Git v2.31.1:** Fix a corner case bug in "git mv" on case insensitive systems, which was introduced in 2.29 timeframe.
- **Fixed in Git v2.21.0:** On a case-insensitive filesystem, we failed to compare the part of the path that is above the worktree directory in an absolute pathname, which has been corrected.
- **Fixed in Git v2.20.0:** Running "git clone" against a project that contain two files with pathnames that differ only in cases on a case insensitive filesystem would result in one of the files lost because the underlying filesystem is incapable of holding both at the same time. An attempt is made to detect such a case and warn.
- **Fixed in Git v2.17.6: CVE-2021-21300:**
  On case-insensitive file systems with support for symbolic links, if Git is configured globally to apply delay-capable clean/smudge filters (such as Git LFS), Git could be fooled into running remote code during a clone.
- **Fixed in Git v2.16:** The code internal to the recursive merge strategy was not fully prepared to see a path that is renamed to try overwriting another path that is only different in case on case insensitive systems. This does not matter in the current code, but will start to matter once the rename detection logic starts taking hints from nearby paths moving to some directory and moves a new path along with them.
- **Fixed in Git v2.1:** On a case insensitive filesystem, merge-recursive incorrectly deleted the file that is to be renamed to a name that is the same except for case differences.
- **Fixed in Git v1.8.3:** The code to keep track of what directory names are known to Git on platforms with case insensitive filesystems could get confused upon a hash collision between these pathnames and would loop forever.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the local file (as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64024705/6309)) is one solution.

Check first if a [`git config --global core.ignoreCase true`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreignoreCase) could help on your next `git pull`.
Check if other users have already set that setting.